comtel2000 Virtual Keyboard JavaFX
I am seeking advice pertaining to my current implementation of the Comtel2000 Keyboard. The keyboard is functioning and does display and close as required. My issue is, for some reason, on my touch screen device the keyboard will randomly resize and move on the screen. I want to maintain the same position on the primary screen at all times. I am obviously missing a concept which is causing the issue. Below is my code in which I have tried to force the keyboard to maintain position and size. I have also tried adding listeners on touch actions with an event.consume(); to see if this would help but it didn't. The code below can be used standalone to check. I call the below method from within my differing classes.
 private void showKeyboard(){
        Tools.showVirtualKeyboard(primaryController.getPrimaryStage());
    }
}

Here is the code:
 public static void showVirtualKeyboard(Stage primaryStage) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if (keyBoardPopup == null) {
                KeyboardPane kb = new KeyboardPane();
                kb.setLayer(DefaultLayer.DEFAULT);
                try {
                    kb.load();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                keyBoardPopup = new KeyBoardPopup(kb);

                // Set fixed dimensions
                double fixedWidth = 800; // Set the desired width
                double fixedHeight = 300; // Set the desired height

                Pane root = new Pane();
                root.setPrefSize(fixedWidth, fixedHeight);
                root.setMinSize(fixedWidth, fixedHeight);
                root.setMaxSize(fixedWidth, fixedHeight);

                Scene scene = new Scene(root, fixedWidth, fixedHeight);
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
                stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

                // Set fixed dimensions for the stage
                stage.setWidth(fixedWidth);
                stage.setHeight(fixedHeight);
                stage.setResizable(false); // Make the stage non-resizable

                keyBoardPopup.show(stage);
                keyBoardPopup.registerScene(primaryStage.getScene());
                keyBoardPopup.setVisible(true);
                kb.setOnKeyboardCloseButton(event -> keyBoardPopup.setVisible(false));

                String key = "virtualkeyboard";
                double scale = 1.0;
                double x = 30;
                double y = 800;
                boolean inBounds = true;
                if (x != 0 && y != 0 && y > 0) {
                    ObservableList<Screen> screenSizes = Screen.getScreens();
                    if (screenSizes.size() == 1) {
                        if (x >= screenSizes.get(0).getBounds().getMaxX() || y >= screenSizes.get(0).getBounds().getMaxY()) {
                            inBounds = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (inBounds) {
                        keyBoardPopup.setX(x);
                        keyBoardPopup.setY(y);
                    }
                }

                // Override stage's size properties to ensure they remain fixed
                stage.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                    if (newVal.doubleValue() != fixedWidth) {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> stage.setWidth(fixedWidth));
                    }
                });

                stage.heightProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                    if (newVal.doubleValue() != fixedHeight) {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> stage.setHeight(fixedHeight));
                    }
                });

                // Remove listeners that might resize or move the popup
                ChangeListener<Number> changeListenerX = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> setWindowX(key, newValue.doubleValue());
                ChangeListener<Number> changeListenerY = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> setWindowY(key, newValue.doubleValue());
                keyBoardPopup.xProperty().addListener(changeListenerX);
                keyBoardPopup.yProperty().addListener(changeListenerY);

                kb.setScale(2);
                kb.scaleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> setScale(key, newValue.doubleValue()));

                // Handle touch events to prevent resizing and moving
                stage.addEventFilter(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVED, event -> {
                    // Prevent moving and resizing via touch events
                    stage.setX(x);
                    stage.setY(y);
                    stage.setWidth(fixedWidth);
                    stage.setHeight(fixedHeight);
                    event.consume();
                });
                stage.addEventFilter(TouchEvent.TOUCH_PRESSED, event -> {
                    // Prevent moving and resizing via touch events
                    stage.setX(x);
                    stage.setY(y);
                    stage.setWidth(fixedWidth);
                    stage.setHeight(fixedHeight);
                    event.consume();
                });
                stage.addEventFilter(TouchEvent.TOUCH_RELEASED, event -> {
                    // Prevent moving and resizing via touch events
                    stage.setX(x);
                    stage.setY(y);
                    stage.setWidth(fixedWidth);
                    stage.setHeight(fixedHeight);
                    event.consume();
                });

            } else {
                keyBoardPopup.setVisible(true);
                // Ensure the size and position are reset when shown again
                keyBoardPopup.setWidth(800);
                keyBoardPopup.setHeight(300);
                keyBoardPopup.setX(30);
                keyBoardPopup.setY(800);
            }
        });
    }

Forces the keyboard stage size, adding listeners.
